# Sails.js autoreload views

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am use **sails-hook-autoreload** in my **sails.js** project, and it works when I make changes in controller. 
What can I do, that it's work, when I make changes in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sails views are read and processed server-side at every new request, no reloading is necessary. If you save changes to a view, the next render will incorporate those changes without needing to restart sails, etc.

Comment: Just complementing, local `.js` and `.css` needs some time to reload (like a few seconds) because of Grunt tasks...